# How can i get sum of Palindromic numbers with specific conditions?

Tags: python, performance, palindrome

I am supposed to write a program to get sum of all palindromic numbers of N digit and these palindromic number should not contain any 0 in them and also should be a multiple of 9?
I have the code what I have written in python and for small values of N it seems to be working fine, but it fails for larger numbers and also it does take lot of time to execute for large values of N.
Could anyone help to find a better logic for this and also works for large values of N?
Thank You in Advance

```
def getSum(N):
 sum=0
 first=pow(10,N-1)
 last=pow(10,N)
 for i in range(first,last):
  if(i%9==0):
   if(palindrome(i)):
    sum+=i
return sum%(pow(10,9)+7)

def palindrome(num):
 rev=0
 n=num
 while(n>0):
  rem=n%10
  if(rem==0):
   return False
  rev=(rev*10)+rem
  n=n//10

 if(num==rev):
  return True
 else:
  return False

def main():
 N=int(input("Enter the value of N "))
 result = getSum(N)
 print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an optimized solution and it is adapted from your idea with a couple exceptions. The first being that instead of considering every number from first to last, start with the first multiple of 9 and last multiple of 9 and consider only multiples of nine. This can be accomplished with the range function `range(first,last,multiple)`. The next is that palindromes can be found simply by comparing a reversed string. Your restrictions are no 0's and palindromes. So type cast to a string really quick and compare the reverse and check for a zero. On a side note, this application will always get expensive as the number becomes larger because you have to go through a list of approximately 10^(N+1)-10^N numbers.

```
def palSum(N):
    multiple = 9
    #Find lower limit
    minBound = multiple*((10**(N-1))//multiple)
    minBound += multiple if len(str(minBound))< N else 0
    #Find upper limit
    maxBound = multiple*((10**(N))//multiple)
    maxBound += multiple if len(str(maxBound))<N+1 else 0
    #Get sum
    sum = 0
    for num in range(int(minBound),int(maxBound),multiple):
        nstr = str(num)
        if '0' not in nstr and nstr[::-1]==nstr:
            sum+=num
    return sum
```

I am currently running a quick timing experiment with `N=10`. I will post the results when they are completed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 10
    s1 = time.time()
    print(getSum(N)) #Original
    s2 = time.time()
    print(palSum(N)) #New
    s3 = time.time()
    print(s2-s1,s3-s2)
```

The results were:

Original:
1859.58 seconds

New: 
277.11 seconds

If you need more performance you could consider a parallel programming approach with a reduction (parallel sum). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and yeah even I am trying to run the same thing for N=10 and it seems to be still running. BTW I was thinking what if we can try to generate the palindromes between the given range and then check if it has 0 and multiple of 9? Wouldn't that be more efficient?

Comment: @ShashankMayya that could be more efficient if the algorithm used to generate them is less expensive than analyzing the list. It would be quite challenging however to only generate the palindromic numbers which are also a multiple of 9. I will think more about it an see if I can come up with anything.